# How to cancel all queued request onFailure? (Retrofit2)

Tags: android, http, retrofit, retrofit2

Actually i'm using Retrofit2 in my app for sending some text to my server.

The issue is when i'm using a Radio Frequency Device when the network is interrupted so i'm getting onFailure the call should be cancelled but as soon as the device is reconnected to the network seems it's resending the text or something like that text remain in queue and i would handle it.

Here is my method where i'm sending the text ( i've yet tryed to use call.cancel() in onFailure but that has no effect )

```
  @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public void sendPost() {
        @SuppressLint({"SdCardPath", "DefaultLocale"}) final File file = new File("/data/data/app/files/"+String.format("%03d", Integer.valueOf(nTerminalino))+"_"+nTavoli.getText().toString()+".txt");

        MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
        builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

        RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/*"), file);
        builder.addFormDataPart(String.format("%03d", Integer.valueOf(nTerminalino))+"_"+nTavoli.getText().toString(), file.getName(),fbody);

        MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();

        final APIService apiService = ApiUtils.getAPIService(ipCASSA);

        final Call<Void> calls = apiService.savePost(requestBody);

        calls.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Void> call, @NonNull Response<Void> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.i("RESPONSE: ", response.toString());
                    Print();
                    file.delete();
                    dialogLoading.dismiss();
                    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                }else {
                    calls.cancel();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Void> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("TAG", t.toString());
                    MediaPlayer mpFound = MediaPlayer.create(pterm.this, R.raw.errorsound);
                    mpFound.start();
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    if (v.hasVibrator()) {
                        v.vibrate(6000);
                    }
                    new GlideToast.makeToast(pterm.this, "CONNESSIONE FALLITA!", GlideToast.LENGTHLONG, GlideToast.FAILTOAST).show();
                    dialogLoading.dismiss();

            }
        });
    }
```

In my class where i'm building OkHttpClient i've set retryOnConnectionFailure(false) but still unable to solve the problem that even onFailure i'm getting the POST request.

**UPDATE:**

After some research i found that OkHttp make's silent retry of POST on connection failure.

So how can i prevent the client to retry?

**SOME INFO:**

*My app is an app for waiter so when i get a `onFailure` message i notify the waiter that the receipt hasn't been received by POS and hasn't been printed but as `OkHttpClient` still retry to sending the file and i'm forcing the waiter to resend the receipt after `onFailure` it cause printing duplicated receipts.*

Here is my ApiUtils class , APIService interface and RetrofitClient class

```
class ApiUtils {

    private ApiUtils() {}



    static APIService getAPIService(String ipCASSA) {

        String BASE_URL = "http://"+ipCASSA+"/web/";

        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                .build();


        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL,okHttpClient).create(APIService.class);
    }
}

public interface APIService {

    @POST("CART=PTERM")
    Call<Void> savePost(@Body RequestBody text);

}

class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what behavior do you see that makes you think the request is sent twice? Do you see it on your server only? Do you see an `onFailure` and when the network is reconnected do you see an `onSuccess`?

Comment: @JanosBreuer actually i'm getting something like described here https://medium.com/inloopx/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace in point "Fix the real problem" I'm sending the file the network is interrupted so i don't get the response but the file is sent

Answer (score 1):

You could try canceling the call directly. So when the call fails, in the `onFailure` callback, you can do something like

```
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Void> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
    if (!call.isCanceled()) {
        // Do receipt logic
        call.cancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `retryOnConnectionFailure(false)` didn't help, the problem is not caused by OKHttp retry.

I suspect you are duplicating the request. Check whether `sendPost()` is getting called multiple times.

Comment: Are you sure that retryOnConnectionFailure will help? as i've read this article https://medium.com/inloopx/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace and it's saying that okhttp is quietly retrying on network error

Comment: actually i've checked the code and i'm calling sendPost() just one tipe when i click "send" button...

Comment: Try adding a log in `sendPost()`. And check if it ever happens more than once.